# Input and symbol on the same line height next to each other in table cell?

Tags: html, css

I have table with td cell and inside of the cells are input element and symbol. They should be next to each other and on the same height as in the td cell with text description. Here is example of what I have:

```css
.tbl {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   <td colspan="2">Form validation text description. Form validation text description. Form validation text description. Form validation text description.</td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="tr_dc1">
      <td>
        <span><input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1"></span>
        <span><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i></span>
      </td>
      <td>Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see in example the checkbox and symbol are on different lines. They should be next to each other on the same height. Also this solution should be compatible in all browsers (IE 9 >, Firefox, Chrome, Safari). If anyone knows good way to fix this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for. I have done some changes in your HTML.

```css
.tbl {
  width: 600px;
}
.icons{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Form validation text description. Form validation text description. Form validation text description. Form validation text description.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_dc1">
      <td class="icons">
        <span><input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1"></span>
        <span><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i></span>
      </td>
      <td>Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My code is exactly what I need. the only problem is that symbol is warping under the input field in td cell. I don't need second row.

Comment: Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, but display flex is not supported in IE. I already had that solution.

Comment: Yeah, IE will have compatibility issues, but, nowadays those sites are few that aim at compatibility in IE, if you want I can provide you with an IE solution as well

Comment: And check [this](https://snag.gy/lzmKv3.jpg) link, its a screenshot of IE 11, it seems to be working fine, without any issues

Answer (score 1):

```css
.tbl {
  width: 600px;
}
.symboltd{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   <td colspan="2">Form validation text description. Form validation text description. Form validation text description. Form validation text description.</td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="tr_dc1">
      <td class="symboltd">
        <span><input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1"></span>
        <span><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i></span>
      </td>
      <td>Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing. Description text for testing.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the vertical height on the checkbox? In your example checkbox is on the very bottom. I would like to vertically align with the symbol and text (to be in center of vertical height).

Comment: Ops my bad, i accidentally edited your codes. Please do not approve my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @espresso_coffee, yes you can vertically align those checkbox and the icon by adding below code:
.symboltd span {display:inline-block;vertical-aligne:middle;}